# How can I use swarm with metamask or parity node?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, metamask, swarm

I want to use swarm, but I wan't to download the all blockchain data. Is it possible to use metamask or  parity node instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any blockchain data to run swarm.

Just install and run swarm directly:

```
go install -v ./cmd/swarm
$GOPATH/bin/swarm version
```

https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-source

Parity and Metamask do not support Swarm (yet?).